# StereoRectifyUncalibrated not accepting same array as FindFundamentalMat

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I've used `FindFundamentalMat` with a `CvMat` I've created from the points generated by `FindChessboardCorners`. The documentation specifies that `StereoRectifyUncalibrated` can use the same format of corresponding points as `FindFundamentalMat`.

However, when I try to use `StereoRectifyUncalibrated`, I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (CV_IS_MAT(_points1) && CV_IS_MAT(_points2) && (_points1->rows == 1 || _points1->cols == 1) && (_points2->rows == 1 || _points2->cols == 1) && CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(_points1, _points2)) in cvStereoRectifyUncalibrated, file /home/moos/prog/opencv/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cv/cvcalibration.cpp, line 2539
```

It seems that the array of points for `StereoRectifyUncalibrated` should be 1 dimensional, but how can I then specify x and y coordinates for the corresponding points?

Previously I did:

```
cv.FindFundamentalMat(points1,points2,F,method=cv.CV_FM_RANSAC,param1=1.,param2=cv.CV_FM_8POINT)
cv.Save("F.xml",F);
cv.StereoRectifyUncalibrated(points1,points2,F,(320,240),H1,H2,threshold=5)
```

The error occurred at `StereoRectifyUncalibrated`(not at `FindFundamentalMat`).

Then I tried :

```
cv.StereoRectifyUncalibrated(points1[1],points2[1],F,(320,240),H1,H2,threshold=5)
```

No error ocurred! But I am not sure if I am doing it right or not.

Comment: Would you mind posting your code snippet.  The docs say thathttp://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/calib3d.html  stereoRectifyUncalibrated takes the same point data structure.  The assertion error in question though does not force the array to be 1D. It specifies that at least one dimension is of size 1 - meaning you have an Nx1 or 1xN vector - the datatype of each element is a CvMat which presumably will be an "element" with two values x,y.

Comment: @Paul I edited the question and added some code.

Comment: And obviously this is not  the right thing. **points1[1] and points[2] **  My problem is the array is not 1D, it is 40 cross 2 matrix.I want something like that : '// Example. Estimation of fundamental matrix using the RANSAC algorithm
int point_count = 100;
vector<Point2f> points1(point_count);
vector<Point2f> points2(point_count);

// initialize the points here ... */
for( int i = 0; i < point_count; i++ )
{
    points1[i] = ...;
    points2[i] = ...;
}

Mat fundamental_matrix =
 findFundamentalMat(points1, points2, FM_RANSAC, 3, 0.99);'

Comment: Have you seen this discussion: http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/StereoRectifyUncalibrated-not-accepting-same-array-as-FindFundamentalMat-td5149185.html     It seems perhaps that either the cvStereoRectifyUncalibrated routine does not take points in the same format as cv::findFundamentalMat or that the cv::findFundamentalMat routine is reshaping your points1/2.  From what I can read the above URL implies that cv::findFundamentalMat actually modifies the points1/2 in which case you need to modify them back(you could re read them after the call to cv::findFundamentalMat)

Comment: Yes! that is exactly the  same question.I have seen it before and couldn't get it, so I posted at here.Thank You for your help :)Now I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So following the `opencv-users` link above, I understood you have to do

```
points1r = points1.reshape((points1.shape[0] * 2, 1))
```

before entering it in `cv2.StereoRectifyUncalibrated`

And it should work.